# Install Ubuntu on UEFI

Tags: system-installation

trying to install Ubuntu dual boot with W10 on a UEFI Asus Zenbook 2. Made a FAT32 partion with the boot flag, a ext4 mounted as /, but every time i try to install and finish the final steps, the installation window says almost finished copying files and then disappears. The mouse cursor turns into the spinning circle infinitely and something about a system app failing shows up. When I reboot it goes straight to W10. Help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ28K.png

Comment: Boot up from Live Ubuntu, then run `sudo parted -l`. Edit question with results. Also need to look at `efibootmgr`.

Comment: like that @PaulBenson

Comment: Well the first thing that looks odd to me is that you have 2 EFI boot partitions on your sda drive, whereas I'd expect to see just the one which should serve both systems. I would run diskmgr in Windows, delete Ubuntu partition, and any other **not Windows** related. Then re-allocate unformatted space for Ubuntu, and attempt another installation. Don't try to make a boot partition. Ubuntu should take care of it. Just make a root partition (and maybe a Home one).

Comment: Check sum the iso

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. You can have two FAT32 and before reboot switch which is the ESP, but rarely required. Copy all files in sda5 to sda2. If just /EFI/ubuntu, easier to just reinstall grub with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Use advanced mode and full reinstall of grub.